# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, kernel, visual-studio-2019, ninja

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I got an error even my PATH has kernel32.lib path.

```
 C:\Users\googi\Desktop\CMakeProject2\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeProject2\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

PATH...

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86
```

And if I try to run on Command Prompt, it says...

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing 
this action. Please install an app or, if one already installed,
create an association in the Defalt Apps Setting page.
```

I tried other these 3 paths but it gave me exact same errors.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\arm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\arm64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I tried this path"?

Comment: I tried to put this path on PATH

Comment: Linker dependencies like libs don't go in `PATH`. `PATH` is for executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your case, I suggest you check these things below:

1. Check if you have installed the Windows SDK for your version.
2. Check if $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib is included in the directories list, if not, manually add it.
3. Check if the value of WindowsSdkDir is correct.

[image]